# Integration by parts - when we do not know the derivative

Tags: calculus, integration

I was just a bit unsure of how this exactly goes. So I was wondering if the following expression is correct:
$$\int_a^b u(x)v(x)\,dx= \left[ \left( \int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt \right) v(x) \right]_{x=a}^{x=b} - \int_a^b \int_{-\infty}^x u(t) v'(x) \, dt \, dx$$

Given that $u(x)$ is defined on the entire real line. Are the limits of the integrals correct, because I'm not sure? Also if $a=-\infty$ what method should I use to solve the limit:
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^x u(t) \, dt \right) v(x) = ?$$

To give some context in the concrete problem I have that actually and $b=\infty$ and $u(x) = (x-\mu) \exp\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$, thus the useful part is that at infinity is 0.

Comment: Where you have $\int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt$, what you need is an antiderivative of $x\mapsto u(x)$, and what you have will certainly serve that purpose if $\int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt$ is suitably well behaved.  But, for example, if $u(t)\ge 1$ for all $t$, then the value of that integral is infinite.  You could just use $\int_0^x u(t)\,dt$.  That differs from what you have by a constant if $\int_{-\infty}^0 u(t)\,dt$ is some finite number.  And for any function that will serve in that role, another that differs from it by a constant will also serve. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So for the case of $u$ being the integral in the second part, that should be fine. Are the rest limits correct? and any idea what to do with the limit?

Comment: I think when integrating by parts with an integral of the form $\int_{-\infty}^b$ I've just done the whole thing as an indefinite integral and then after that's done, let the lower bound of integration approach $-\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have $\int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt$, what you need is an antiderivative of $x\mapsto u(x)$, and what you have will certainly serve that purpose if $\int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt$ is suitably well behaved.  But, for example, if $u(t)\ge 1$ for all $t$, then the value of that integral is infinite.  You could just use $\int_0^x u(t)\,dt$.  That differs from what you have by a constant if $\int_{-\infty}^0 u(t)\,dt$ is some finite number.  And for any function that will serve in that role, another that differs from it by a constant will also serve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part? I mean isn't it $\int u'v = uv - \int u v'$, where $u=\int u(t)dt$ and $v=v(x)$.

Comment: I've deleted that second part.  Your notation is confusing.  It's $\int w'v=wv-\int wv'$, where $v(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x u(t)\,dt$. ${}\qquad{}$